# Is this proof on change of basis redundant or not?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-explanation

To proving the following theorem,

> ## $A$
>
> Suppose $P$ is an $n\times n$ invertible matrix over $F$. Let $V$ be an n-dimensional vector space over $F$, and let $\mathfrak{B}$ be an ordered basis of $V$.
>
> ---
>
> ## $B$
>
> Then there is a unique ordered basis $\mathfrak{B}^{'}$ of V such that $$[\alpha]_{\mathfrak{B}}=P[\alpha]_{\mathfrak{B}^{'}}$$ $$[\alpha]_{\mathfrak{B}^{'}}=P^{-1}[\alpha]_{\mathfrak{B}}$$ for every vector $\alpha$ in $V$.

I don't think it's necessary to show that $B\mapsto A$ ***because the theorem states only $A\mapsto B$ not $A=B$***. However, the proof on the book suggests that:

> ## $B\mapsto A$
>
> Let $\mathfrak{B}$ consist of the vectors $\alpha_{1},\ldots,\alpha_{n}$. If $\mathfrak{B}^{'}=\{\alpha_{1}^{'},\ldots,\alpha_{n}^{'}\}$ is an ordered basis of $V$ for which (i) is valid, it is clear that $$\alpha_{j}^{'}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}P_{ij}\alpha_{i}.$$
>
> ---
>
> ## $A\mapsto B$
>
> Thus we need only show that the vectors $\alpha_{j}^{'}$, defined by these equations, form a basis...

Am I right or mistaken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have misinterpreted the structure of the argument in the book. The author is only proving the assertion $A \Rightarrow B$. Under your heading $B \mapsto A$, the author is providing motivation for the proof, which begins under your label $A \mapsto B$.  In effect, the definition of $\mathcal{B}'$ given in $A \mapsto B$ might seem to come "out of thin air" if not for the observation in $B \mapsto A$ that if such a basis $\mathcal{B}'$ did exist, it would necessarily have a certain form.

Answer (score 0):

You're right. To show that this is true you have to use the fact that $P$ is invertible (if $P$ is not invertible of course it is false). Let me know if you want the solution.

Comment: The proof is already given in this book. I will accept your answer if there ain't other opinions in few days.

Comment: What was you question then? I think that what you wrote was right, and that to use the matrix $P$ is useful to write the linear combination of the vectors

Comment: My question was to check if **the proof given in this book** is redundant in the way that $B\mapsto A$ is unnecessary.

Comment: no, it's necessary because it's needed for the other proof.. To me it doesn't feel reduntant at all!!

Comment: and I add, I would have done it exactly the same way of the book.. Not to say that the way I do things is the best, but to highlight the fact that the book respects the way an average undergraduate that has already studied the subject thinks.. It's very good fot the comprehension

Comment: I'm not saying that the theorem is useless, rather that the proof on this theorem is a bit misleading because it sounds like the theorem states $A=B$. If you're not saying that $B\mapsto A$ must be proved, why is it necessary?